# give a minimum height to a MaterializeCSS carousel

Tags: html, css, materialize

I would like to use a MaterializeCSS carousel for my website. It needs to span the whole width of the page but not get under 400px in height, in this case I would like to crop both sides to keep the carousel height at 400px when the window width shrinks.

This is what I've tried :

```css
.carousel {
      min-height: 400px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="carousel carousel-slider center" data-indicators="true">

      <div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
        <h1 class="header futural center white-text animated fadeInUp">Futural</h1>
        <div class="row center">
          <h5 class="header col s12 light white-text animated fadeInUp delay-animation">Fabricant de menuiserie aluminium à haute performance énergétique</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="row center">
          <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/about.html" class="btn waves-effect white grey-text darken-text-2 animated fadeInUp delay-button">Nous contacter</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x340/f44336/b71c1c"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x340/4caf50/1b5e20"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x340/ffeb3b/f57f17"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x340/2196f3/0d47a1"></a>
    </div>
```

But this solution only seems to fix the size of the carousel-fixed-item element.
The image keeps the same ratio and it shrinks behind the fixed elements.

Do you see a solution to this problem ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi, I made a jsfiddle, does this fix your problem? https://jsfiddle.net/7kvtyahj/2/

Comment: This is exactly what I needed ! Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome, I posted an answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-image` with   `background-size : cover` ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size))  to display an image that covers an entire element without losing the aspect ratio of the picture, `background-position : center` allows you to center the picture inside the element.

Link of a working JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7kvtyahj/2/

CSS

```
.carousel {
  min-height: 400px;
}

.carousel-item
{
  background-size : cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.c1
{
  background-image : url(' http://via.placeholder.com/1000x340/2196f3/0d47a1');
}

.c2
{
  background-image : url(' http://via.placeholder.com/1000x340/4caf50/1b5e20');
}

.c3
{
  background-image : url(' http://via.placeholder.com/1000x340/2196f3/0d47a1');
}

 .c4
{
  background-image : url(' http://via.placeholder.com/1000x340/4caf50/1b5e20');
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="carousel carousel-slider center" data-indicators="true">
  <div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
    <h1 class="header futural center white-text animated fadeInUp">Futural</h1>
    <div class="row center">
      <h5 class="header col s12 light white-text animated fadeInUp delay-animation">Fabricant de menuiserie aluminium à haute performance énergétique</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="row center">
      <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/about.html" class="btn waves-effect white grey-text darken-text-2 animated fadeInUp delay-button">Nous contacter</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="carousel-item c1" href="#one!"></a> <!--Notice that I removed the <img> tags and added the classes c1, c2, c3 and c4 in the <a> elements -->
  <a class="carousel-item c2" href="#two!"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item c3" href="#three!"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item c4" href="#four!"></a>
</div>
```